Retrieve the count of occurrences for each hashtag mentioned in the tweets
I have a tweets table in my PieCloudDB Database. Suppose I have the following sample data:



user_id
tweet_id
tweet_date
tweet




128
6
2024-02-01
#life is full of surprises.


133
9
2024-02-01
I am #happy with my achievements.


146
13
2024-02-04
NoSQL vs SQL. #database #tech


150
14
2024-02-05
The sunny weather made everyone #happy!


155
18
2024-02-07
#PieCloudDB is a cloud native #database.


156
19
2024-02-10
#happy people radiate positive energy. #optimism


168
30
2024-03-02
What a #life!



I now want to count the number of times hashtags appear in tweets in February, and sort them in descending order of counts and ascending order of hashtag names(
Note that each tweet may have multiple hashtags). For the above example data, I hope to get the following results:



hashtag
hashtag_count




#happy
3


#database
2


#life
1


#optimism
1


#PieCloudDB
1


#tech
1



I tried the following query:
SELECT hashtag, COUNT(*) AS hashtag_count
FROM (
    SELECT 
        tweet_id,
        UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(SUBSTRING(tweet, POSITION('#' IN tweet)), ' ')) AS hashtag
    FROM tweets
    WHERE tweet_date >= '2024-02-01' AND tweet_date < '2024-03-01'
) AS subquery
WHERE hashtag LIKE '#%'
GROUP BY hashtag
ORDER BY hashtag_count DESC, hashtag ASC

But I discovered a problem. The hashtag that appears at the end will count the punctuation marks such as . or ! :



hashtag
hashtag_count




#happy
2


#database
1


#database.
1


#happy!
1


#life
1


#optimism
1


#PieCloudDB
1


#tech
1



Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Maybe use TRANSLATE and remove . and !? Something like TRANSLATE(SUBSTRING(tweet, POSITION('#' IN tweet)),'!,.',''), see this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/VigLTpIn It's hard to tell if this is the best idea because we don't know what strings are possible, for example whether those characters can also appear within the hashtag or really at the end only. Could you please describe your use cases more detailed?

I just want to know which hashtags are more popular, but various punctuation marks in tweets (not just . or !) can sometimes affect the statistics of hashtags, and I want to avoid punctuation being recognized as part of the hashtag.

You can try to use regular expressions to solve this problem.(I'm not really sure this works with PieCloudDB), I just tested it in PostgreSQL.
SELECT unnest(regexp_matches(tweet, '#\w+', 'g')) AS hashtag, COUNT(*) AS hashtag_count
FROM tweets
WHERE tweet_date >= '2024-02-01' AND tweet_date < '2024-03-01'
GROUP BY hashtag
ORDER BY hashtag_count DESC, hashtag ASC

